# Youtube Api get user's subscriped channels

Tags: json, api, youtube, httprequest

I'm coding a app which needs to get a list of subscribed channels of the user.
So the user gets navigated to this page so I can get the authorization key:
[Get Access key for my App "AboReminder"](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=798670064871-f901n0lkag15aq7tnd8mh2unrm8q4plq.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob:auto&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube.force-ssl%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube.readonly%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutubepartner&response_type=code&access_type=offline&pageId=none)

Now I get the access key which I need for some api requests. But I am stuck on the issue that I dont have any glue how to get the subscription list.

I'm not able to understand the information on the google page: [Google APi documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list)

So my question how is a possible request for getting all subscriped channels of the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

send an ajax request to the following URL after replacing the {{OAUTHKEY}} with the appropriate user authorization key

https://content.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=id,contentDetails,snippet&maxResults=10&mine=true&key={{OAUTHKEY}}

This should be a GET request and no request body required to set.

You can navigate to the next set of results using 'nextPageToken' in the response.

By default api can generate only 5 results. You can get upto 50 results by providing 'maxResults' query parameter.

As far as I know, there is no way to get all the list.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped me